# Как установить приоритет отображение на экране?

Tags: java, javafx

Если на экран добавляется новый элемент, то он в любом случае делается "выше" чем всё, что появлялось на экран до него. То есть все вновь появившиеся объекты накладываются на старые. Так вот вопрос, каким образом регулировать этот самый приоритет? Как сделать, что бы старый объект мог быть выше новых и наоборот?

Answer (score 2):

Z-порядок элементов на экране в JavaFX зависит от его положения относительно соседей в дереве сцены.

Влиять на него можно вызовом методов `toFront()` и `toBack()`.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста в каком виде оно должно быть. откуда вызывать такие методы?

Comment: Добавили несколько элементов, заставил нужный всплыть через `.toFront()`.

Comment: всё равно как то не ясно, можно как то подробнее? ничего не нашел даже в книге о JavaFX ничего нет об этом, только пару слов. что то в духе Rectangle.toBack() и всё. в моём случае не помогло

Comment: Может быть, вы приведете пример кода из вашего случая в вопросе?

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам пример работы toFront() с двумя прямоугольниками:

```
Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(200, 200);
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(200, 200);

root.getChildren().add(rect1, rect2);

rect1.toFront(); // Теперь rect1 находится выше, чем rect2
```

И, пожалуйста, приводите свой код в вопросе.